# Trying to run ripple-lib with node facing syntax error

Tags: node.js

Trying to run the rippleApi with ripple-lib facing issues like syntaxerror .
Am new to Node and ripple-lib . Please guide me to get rid of this. Thanks in advance

```
node ripple.js
```

My Code in ripple.js is

```
const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;

const Ripple = new RippleAPI({
server: 'wss://s1.ripple.com:443'
});

Ripple.on('error', function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
resp.json('{"status":0,"msg":"Unable to withdraw, problem occured. '+errorMessage+'."}');
});

Ripple.on('connected', function () {
});
Ripple.on('disconnected', function (code) {
console.log('disconnected, code:', code);
});
Ripple.connect().then(function () {
return Ripple.getServerInfo();
}).then(function (server_info) {

var rippleAddress = Ripple.generateAddress();

console.log(rippleAddress);process.exit(-1);

}).catch(console.error);
```

The Output am getting is

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/ripple-lib/dist/npm/api.js:83
    constructor(options = {}) {
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/ripple-lib/dist/npm/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? I think this is a newer feature in javascript that requires a more recent version.

Comment: @Atsch using v4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade nodejs

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```